# How to find out the correct link of the web table to copy with Urlfetch in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to get data from a table of a website. I was reading about the URL Fetch Service of Google App Scripts, I understand it, but cannot find what is the correct link to evaluate.

I tried this:

https://www.codelco.com/prontus_codelco/site/edic/base/port/licitaciones_enproceso.html

This is the basic code: (when I find the correct link I will develop more)
    function getCodelcoTable() {

```
var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.codelco.com/prontus_codelco/site/edic/base/port/licitaciones_enproceso.html'); 
Logger.log(html.getContentText());
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the values you want?

Comment: @Tanaike, sorry but cannot understand your question. You are asking for the table values?

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `the correct link`. But it seems that `the correct link` is the value you want. So I asked about the value of `the correct link`. But now I noticed that an answer had already been posted. It will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Code

It seems there is what you need

```
/**
 * Parses the first html-table from the content. max 7 columns
 *
 * @param {string} content A html string
 * @returns {Array.<Array.<object>>}
 */
function parseHtmlTableToArray_(content) {
  var inline = content.replace(/[\n\r]/g, ' ');
  var table = inline.split(/<table.*?>/)[1].split(/<\/table>/)[0];

  return table.split(/<tr.*?>/).map(function(row) {
    return (
      row
        .split(/(<td.*?>|<th.*?>)/)
        .slice(2)
        .reduce(function(p, cell, i) {
          if (~i % 2) {
            p.push(
              cell
                .replace(/<.*?>/g, ' ')
                .replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
                .replace(/^\s+/g, '')
                .replace(/\s+$/g, '')
            );
          }
          return p;
        }, [])
        .join(PLACEHOLDER) + PLACEHOLDER.repeat(7)
    )
      .split(PLACEHOLDER)
      .slice(0, 7);
  });
}
```

You need to define `PLACEHOLDER` and pass your data to `parseHtmlTableToArray_`.

### Run

For an example you can exec this like:

```
var PLACEHOLDER = '----YADA-YADA----';

function userActionRun() {
  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    'https://www.codelco.com/prontus_codelco/site/edic/base/port/licitaciones_enproceso.html'
  ).getContentText();

  var data = parseHtmlTableToArray_(content);

  SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXX')
    .getSheets()[0]
    .clearContents()
    .getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length)
    .setValues(data);
}
```

### Result

[image]

### Notes

Don't miss add the [`String.repeat` polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

### Links

- [The full snippet](https://github.com/oshliaer/google-apps-script-snippets/tree/master/snippets/standalone_parse-html-table)

  - [`String.repeat`](https://github.com/oshliaer/google-apps-script-snippets/blob/master/shims/String.repeat.js)
- [The full project example](https://script.google.com/d/18X9hFekFuVTD4WUYEH-F4ZAwrOaNYOgSYcaYFL1RbT1aRXDHrEKEBad_/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. I read your code and look your result and looks very fine!. I tried to add the polyfill String.prototype.repeat as you indicated, (from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) but it doesn´t work for me. The other thing, is about the Placeholder, what is the purpose and what name or text I have to put?

Comment: @GermánRogersTirado there is a full project example https://script.google.com/d/18X9hFekFuVTD4WUYEH-F4ZAwrOaNYOgSYcaYFL1RbT1aRXDHrEKEBad_/edit?usp=sharing Also I need use `PLACEHOLED` for split/join strings. You can put there any string that you think may be unique. In some cases it may happen that this string is not unique and needs to be replaced. Use the variable for to do this.

Comment: I realize I'm having issues with the dates extracted from the Url.